# How to save the state on exit when detecting CTRL+C SIGINT

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing a NodeJS application which performs some calculations. When the application starts it is able to load data from file to continue where it left off. I haven't yet figured out the best way of saving the data to file when an interrupt signal is obtained, which signals that the application should finish computation and shutdown.

Here's a simplified version of what I have so far:

```
const filesystem = require('fs');

process.on('SIGINT', function onSigInt() {
    console.log('SIGINT ', new Date().toISOString());
    shutdown();
})

// This function should somehow save the data to file
function shutdown() {
    process.exit();
}

async function run() {

    let allData = [];

    // Load existing database from file, if exists
    try {
        const fileData = filesystem.readFileSync('output.json', {encoding:'utf-8', flag:'r'});
        allData = JSON.parse(data.toString());
        console.log(`Loaded {allData.length} records from file`);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('No file to load data from, continuing with empty dataset');
    }

    while(true) {
        doCalculation(allData);
    }

    // If we run out of things to calculate, and the infinite loop above
    // ends, then we save data to file like this:
    filesystem.writeFileSync('output.json', JSON.stringify(allData, null, 4));
}
```

The object containing the dataset is `allData`. Do I need to make this a global variable? This would seem the most obvious solution. I am new to JavaScript - there might be an alternative way of doing things in JS?

Comment: Note that it's `true` in JavaScript, not `True`, which will be `false` unless you declare it as `true` :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Good spot, I've fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I am not a JavaScript guru, but yes I think having a global variable for your use case should be good.

**EDIT**
A simple example with allData as a global variable, I added a new saveToFile function.

Following your naming convention :

```javascript
const filesystem = require('fs');

//Make allData global
let allData = [];

process.on('SIGINT', function onSigInt() {
    console.log('SIGINT ', new Date().toISOString());
    shutdown();
})

//You can call saveToFile before exiting the process
function shutdown() {
    saveToFile()
    process.exit();
}

//Common function to save the data to file
function saveToFile(){
      filesystem.writeFileSync('output.json', JSON.stringify(allData, null, 4));
}

async function run() {

     try {
        const fileData = filesystem.readFileSync('output.json', {encoding:'utf-8', flag:'r'});
        allData = JSON.parse(data.toString());
        console.log(`Loaded {allData.length} records from file`);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('No file to load data from, continuing with empty dataset');
    }
    while(True) {
        doCalculation(allData);
    }
    
    // Reuse the saveToFile function 
    saveToFile()
}
```

I am however not sure how you are dealing with your async run function. If it's purely a blocking function, the SIGINT event won't be processed. If you have multiple await point or the like for the asynchronous function, it should be good.

---

Another way, if possible, would be to keep the while loop condition as a global variable, and set it to false, when handling the SIGINT signal. When the while loop exits, your file will be filled with the processed data, from your workflow.

If it works for you, go ahead with any of methods.
As for readability, I don't find it so bad

---

**The following sections are quite long and more for curiosity**

An other interesting approach (personal taste) I am currently exploring, will be the use of [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) which is more or less similar to python coroutine.

For me, your question raises some interesting thoughts about long running CPU bounded operations and cancellation of tasks.
So I will digress quite a bit.

If you are new to JavaScript/NodeJS, I will use some standard function like [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval), [setImmediate](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/understanding-setimmediate/) and JavaScript's [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

---

For the case of cpu bounded function, the single thread event loop will be blocked and can not process other events, like process.on('SIGINT',callback) or whatever. Typically for this use case, you have several options :

1. Worker threads or child processes
2. A distributed tasks-queue system, like [bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull)
3. Process your computation in chunk, and call setImmediate at some point, providing a callback that will be execute later, at the next iteration of the event loop.
4. Tell me please, I'll be glad to learn new things :)

For a one big task like yours, I think the first two approaches will be an overkill, although you can maybe split your data between multiple threads / processes if some chunks are unrelated.

The third option might be interesting with setImmmediate, but it is usually cumbersome to put the callback and maintain the scope of what has been done.

With the combination of function generators and setImmediate, we can yield the long running function at various points of the operation, the function is stopped at some point when yielding and we call setImmediate to let the event-loop handle other events. When it is done, once again we can progress the long running function until an other yield point.

We can repeat this cycle until the long running function is done or we can intercept some events telling us to stop the long running function.

With an example, I hope it will be clearer.

```javascript
/* Your UpperBound, you can increase it, 
   the function with yield will be of course slower
*/
const UPPERBOUND = 10 

//Plain bigCalculation loop
function bigCalculation() {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < UPPERBOUND; i++) {
        count += i;
    }

    return count
}

// Function generator, to yield the execution at some point
function* bigCalculationYielder() {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < UPPERBOUND; i++) {
        count += i;
        yield count // the yield to suspend the current loop.


        /*
          conditonal yielding when count is a modulo of 100,
          for better performance or use cases
          if(count %100){
            yield count
          }
        */


    }
    return count
}

function yieldCalculation() {
    const calculationYielder = bigCalculationYielder() // get the generator()
    function loop() {
       /*
        Calling next on the generator progress the function 
        until the next yield point
        */
        const iteration = calculationYielder.next() 
        
        console.log(iteration) 
        
        // When the iteration is done, we can quit the function
        if (iteration.done) {
            clearInterval(id) // stopping the setInterval function
            return
        }

        // Shorter way
        //setImmediate(()=>{loop()} 
        

        setImmediate(() => {
            // set a litlle time out to see the log pin from the set interval
            return setTimeout(() => loop(), 50) 
        }) // The set immediate function will make progress on the event loop
    }
    return loop()
}

// A setInterval to see if we can interleave some events with a calculation loop
const id = setInterval(() => console.log("ping"), 50) 
const task = yieldCalculation()

/*You can increase the UPPERBOUND constant and use the classic
 bigCalculation function. Until this function end, you won't see the 
 setInterval ping message
*/
```

We are trying in this example to interleave the progress of the function and the events receive from setInterval.

We can call generator.next() to progress the calculation.
If the calculation is done, we clear the setInterval and timer and return the function, otherwise we call setImmediate, NodeJS can process other events and call back again the loop function to finish the calculation.

---

This kind of approach can works with Promise too,
Promise are a bit nicer than callback. You can define some work in a Promise and once it resolve (end the function with success) you can chain operations with a .then to obtain the result of the promise and do something with it.
Promise are often use with async operation, but it is quite flexible.

```javascript
const promise=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    let i=100;
    setTimeout(()=>{
        resolve(i)
        return;
    },2000); // We wait 2 seconds before resolving the promise
})

console.log(promise) // The promise is pending

promise.then(val=>console.log("finish computation with : ",val)) 
/* once 2 secondes ellapsed, we obtain the result 
which been declared in resolve(), inside the promise 
*/
```

From the previous example with function generator, we can make our yieldCalculation function return a promise. (I changed the name sorry)

Only when we have finish the big computation, we can resolve it and chain it with a then

```javascript
const UPPERBOUND = 10

function* bigCalculationYielder() {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < UPPERBOUND; i++) {
        count += i;
        yield count
    }
    return count
}

function yieldHandler() {
    const calculationYielder = bigCalculationYielder() 
    
    /* this time we return a promise, once it the iteration is done
       we will set the value through resolve and return 
    */
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        function loop() {

            const iteration = calculationYielder.next() 
            console.log(iteration)
            
      
            if (iteration.done) {

                // you are setting the value here 
                resolve(iteration.value) 
                return
            }
            //setImmediate(()=>{loop()})
            setImmediate(() => {
                return setTimeout(() => { loop() }, 50)
            })

        }

        loop()
    })

}

const id = setInterval(() => console.log("ping"), 50)
const task = yieldHandler()
console.log(task)

/* When the computation is finished, task.then will be evaluated
   and we can chain other operations
*/
task.then(val=>{console.log("finished promise computation with : ",val); clearInterval(id)})
```

---

With these examples, we saw we can perform a "long" operation in several chunks and let NodeJS handle other events.
Promise is a bit nicer for operation chaining.

For your use case, we are missing two pieces :

- How to handle SIGINT signal to interrupt the long running operation
- How to save the file once the long running operation finished or has been interrupted

In this last example, I will create a Task Class, to handle the running loop of the function generator, it will also "intercept" the SIGINT signal.

The example will create an object, of the form: `{datas:[ {a,b} , {a,b} , {a,b} , {a,b} ,...]}`
And write it to a file

```javascript
"use strict";
// used for class declaration, it is javascript strict mode

const fs = require('fs')

// Depending on how fast is your machine
// you can play with these numbers to get a long task and see cancellation with SIGINT
const UPPERBOUND_TASK=10000
const UPPERBOUND_COMPUTATION=10000

// An async generator
// Not usefull here but can be if you want to fetch data from API or DB
async function* heayvyTask() {
  let jsonData = { datas: [] };
  let i=0;

  while (true) {
    
    if(i==UPPERBOUND_TASK){
      break
    }
    heavyComputation(jsonData)
    i++

    // We yield after the headyComputation has been process.
    // Like that we can fill the data by chunck and prevent from yielding too much
    yield jsonData
    
  }
  return jsonData
}

// The effective process.
// We populate the jsonData object
function heavyComputation(jsonData) {
  for (let i = 0; i < UPPERBOUND_COMPUTATION; i++) {
    const data = { a: i, b: i + 1 }
    jsonData.datas.push(data)
  }
}

// Saving the data to a local file
function saveDataToFile(jsonData) {
  console.log(jsonData.datas.length)
  console.log("saving data to file")
  fs.writeFileSync("test.json", JSON.stringify(jsonData))
  console.log("done")
}

class Task {
  constructor(process) {

    //heayvyTask function
    this.process = process

    this.cancelTask = false
  }
  start() {
    
    // We are getting the heayvyTask function generator
    const process = this.process()
    
    
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        // Declaration of the loop function
        async function loop() {

          // Here we are using an async function generator
          // So we have to await it
          // It can be usefull if you peform async operation in it
          // Same as before your are running the function till the next yield point
          const val = await process.next()

          // If the generator function completed
          // We are resolving the promise with jsonData object value
          if (val.done) {
            console.log("task complete")
            resolve(val.value)
            return
          }

          // If the task has been canceled
          // this.cancelTask is true and we resolve the promise
          // All the data handled by the generator will be pass to the promise.then() 
          if (this.cancelTask) {
            console.log("stopping task")
            resolve(val.value)
            return
          }
          
          // Crazy looping
          setImmediate( ()=>{
            work()
          })
        }

        // We use bind to pass the this context to another function
        // Particulary, we want to access this.cancelTask value
        // It is related to "this scope" which can be sometimes a pain
        // .bind create an other function   
        const work=loop.bind(this)
        
        // Effectively starting the task
        work()
      }
      catch (e) {
        reject(e)
        return
      }
    })
  }

  // We want to cancel the task
  // Will be effetive on the next iteration
  cancel() {
    this.cancelTask = true
    return
  }
}

/* We create a task instance
The heavytask generator has been pass as an attribute of the Task instance
*/
let task = new Task(heayvyTask);

// We are running the task.
// task.start() returns a promise
// When the promise resolves, we save the json object to a file with saveDataToFile function
// This is called when the calculation finish or when the task has been interupted
task.start().then(val => saveDataToFile(val)).catch(e=>console.log(e))

// When SIGINT is called, we are cancelling the task
// We simply set the cancelTask attribute to true
// At the next iteration on the generator, we detect the cancellation and we resolve the promise
process.on('SIGINT',()=>task.cancel())
```

The basic flows are :

- With SIGINT signal

Task Instance -> running the task -> SIGINT -> resolve the promise -> Save the data to file

- Running to the end

Task Instance -> running the task -> end of generator function -> resolve the promise -> Save the data to file

In all case, your file will be saved in the same manner, once the promise has been resolved.

Performance wise, of course generator function with yielding is slower, but it can offers some kind of cooperation, concurrency on the single thread event loop, which is nice and can leverage interesting use cases.

Looping with setImmediate seems okay. I got some errors with heap stack overflow but I think it's related to the array ending too large.
I also got some issues if the string ended being too large, when saving it to file

For the call stack, calling the loop in a recursive way, it looks setImmediate plays nice with it but I did not investigate too much.

---

Without further knowledge of the doCalculation function, I can only recommend to put yield point where it makes sense.
If the calculation follow some kind of transaction style, maybe at the end of it. Otherwise, you can have several yield point in it.
Until the return statement is called, the loop will push the generator function further

If you are curious about long running tasks with generator functions, it seems [this project](https://github.com/dfilatov/lrt) provides some nice API. I didn't play with it, but the documentation looks good.

Comment: "I think having a global variable for your use case should be good" - A global variable won't store any state because it will just be destroyed when `process.exit()` is called.

Comment: @MichaelM. If allData is a global variable, when process.on("SIGINT") is called, could we not save the file with it, before we exit the process ? I don't see why we couldn't

Comment: If that is what you meant, then your answer does not convey that enough (it is notably missing from the first line in your answer). You might want to [edit] your answer to add that clarification.

Comment: You're right, I didn't go into it, will update, thanks for feedback

Comment: To clarify one thing, yes the function calls are asynchronous, so `await` appears all over the place as part of the main calculation process. This is actually a good point about the blocking nature of the calculation thread, so I suppose if someone else were to use this as a template, they would have to write the computation in such a way that it suspends and resumes itself in an asynchronous way, to allow processing of other events.